# JSF web application not working in IE9. But it works fine in IE8

Tags: jsf-2, browser, internet-explorer-9

I have developed web application using JSF 2.0. It is working fine in IE 8 and other browsers (firefox and google chrome). But it is not working in IE9. Can you please explain the IE9 compatibility for JSF and how it could be done so that I can make my App works in IE9.

Comment: Maybe you have problems with some JSF tags...Which JSF tags you are using?

Comment: I am using <f:ajax> <h:commandLink>  <h:panelGroup>   etc...

Comment: Try to remove the <f:ajax> from the XHTML file and give it a try..

Comment: If I remove <f:ajax> tags then how do I achieve rendering particular id alone from the xhtml...???

Answer (score 1):

We also had some issues with IE9 and our workaround was to use a filter that tells the IE9 to work in compatibility mode.

*Notice that this should be the last resort. You should first try to solve your concrete problem (which is not clearly explained in your question) before using a filter.*

The compatibility mode causes IE9 to loose rounded corners.

```
@WebFilter("*.xhtml")
public class CompatibilityFilter implements Filter {

    public CompatibilityFilter() { }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        resp.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE8");
        resp.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        chain.doFilter(request, resp);
    }

    public void destroy() { }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already tried the way u mentioned. Its working fine after adding below header with response in filter. resp.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE8");
But on pressing F12 developer toll kit will open. In that, when you change the document mode to IE9 standards , the problem still exists. Can u help me...???

Comment: The `web.xml` registration is unnecessary if you already have the `@WebFilter` annotation. The URL pattern is however wrong. Shouldn't it be `@WebFilter("*.xhtml")` or `@WebFilter(servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})`?

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for clarifying. So we were lucky that it worked in spite of our misconfiguration... Updated my answer.

Comment: XML config overrides the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but you probably are experiencing/experienced the same defect we did:

```
> <f:ajax/> not working at all in IE9 (normal mode) 
> Created: 18/May/11
> Component/s:  ajax 
> Affects Version/s: 2.1.1    
> Fix Version/s:    2.1.7, 2.2.0-m01
```

See the JIRA:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2063

The signal that this is the issue is if you are getting:

> "malformedXML: Unable to get value of the property 'removeChild':
>   object is null or undefined".

in your browser console.

The solution would be to move to 2.1.7 or later.